# Instagram API: how to make in popular feed see user

Tags: php, javascript, api, instagram

I have this code and as you can see I can see how much likes every photo has, but i want to know username of person who uploaded every photo. What should I write ?

```
            var str = '<p>likes: '+ photo.likes.count +'</p><img id="' + photo.id + '" src="' + photo.images.standard_resolution.url + '" width="50">';
            $('<div></div>').addClass('photo').html(str).appendTo('#p' + photo.id);

            $('#' + photo.id).load(function() {
                $('#p' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });

        }
    }else{
        alert('empty');
    }

}else{
    alert(data.meta.error_message);
}
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the `photo` object to see what else it contains? I suspect it contains a `user` property or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The data json object is described on the site:http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/
This is what you need to use

```
data.user.username
```